# Microsoft Access 2010 Combobox Row Source

Tags: database, combobox, ms-access-2010

[image]

I have the relationship seen in the image. In Spare Components Inventory the System and Subsystem are of type number which correlate to the keys in the system list and sub system list tables.

In the Spare Components Inventory Table the fields System and Subsystem are combo boxes which are drop downs from their respective tables. In order to fill the row source of the combo box for the field System I use the SQL code:

```
 SELECT [Systems List].[ID], [Systems List].[System] FROM [Systems List];
```

Which uses the ID number to filter but displays the system text instead of the number in the Spare Comp. Table.

For Subsystem I run a similar code:

```
SELECT [Subsystem List].ID, [Subsystem List].Subsystem FROM [Subsystem List];
```

but it displays the ID number instead of the Name associated with it. I have tried editing the query and the fields but am unable to reproduce the results from System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Column Count to 2 and Column Widths to 0";1". This allows the user to see both columns from the table but hides the first one so only my text is seen.